# Changing the colour of elements in a List Box / List Model

Tags: java

If a room is in emergency mode then I would like to display it on the list box as red. My List box uses a List Model to display all of it's items.
[GUI displaying the rooms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbAnZ.png)
Is there anyway of looping through each element in the List Box to change the colour of its text?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568646/getting-back-data-from-jlist

Comment: What is a "list box"? What Java GUI library are you using? Swing? JavaFX?

Comment: I am using Swing and I mean a JList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a custom cell renderer. The example below is cribbed from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html):

```
public class MyCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer<Object> {
     final static ImageIcon longIcon = new ImageIcon("long.gif");
     final static ImageIcon shortIcon = new ImageIcon("short.gif");

     // This is the only method defined by ListCellRenderer.
     // We just reconfigure the JLabel each time we're called.

     public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
       JList<?> list,           // the list
       Object value,            // value to display
       int index,               // cell index
       boolean isSelected,      // is the cell selected
       boolean cellHasFocus)    // does the cell have focus
     {
         String s = value.toString();
         setText(s);
         if (room.getMode() == RoomConstants.EMERGENCY_MODE) {
             setForeground(Color.RED);
         } 
         setEnabled(list.isEnabled());
         setFont(list.getFont());
         setOpaque(true);
         return this;
     }
 }

 myList.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what are the image icons needed for?

Comment: That's from the sample code. It's been omitted now for clarity's sake

Comment: If this solution worked for you, kindly accept and vote it up, so others who come across this problem in the future know that it's helpful.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the help, I finally got it working after a bit of research! However, I am unable to up vote your reply as I have under 15 reputation.